# Choose the best cluster partition based on a cost function

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I've a string that I'd like to cluster:

```
s = 'AAABBCCCCC'
```

I don't know in advance how many clusters I'll get. All I have, is a cost function that can take a clustering and give it a score.

There is also a constraint on the cluster sizes: they must be in a range [a, b]

In my exemple, for `a=3` and `b=4`, all possible clustering are:

```
[
    ['AAA', 'BBC', 'CCCC'],
    ['AAA', 'BBCC', 'CCC'],
    ['AAAB', 'BCC', 'CCC'],
]
```

Concatenation of each clustering must give the string `s`

The cost function is something like this

```
cost(clustering) = alpha*l + beta*e + gamma*d
```

where:

- `l = variance(cluster_lengths)`
- `e = mean(clusters_entropies)`
- `d = 1 - nb_characters_in_b_that_are_not_in_a)/size_of_b` (for `b` the
  consecutive cluster of `a`)
- `alpha`, `beta`, `gamma` are weights

This cost function gives a low cost (0) for the best case:

1. Where all clusters have the same size.
2. Content inside each cluster is the same.
3. Consecutive clusters don't have the same content.

Theoretically, the solution is to calculate the cost of all possible [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) for this string and choose the lowest. but It will take too much time.

Is there any clustering algorithme that can find the best clustering according to this cost function in a reasonable time ?

Comment: That Wikipedia page defines compositions only for numbers.  What's a composition of a string?

Comment: for a string 'abc', compositions are {['a', 'b', 'c'], ['ab', 'c'], ['a', 'bc'], ['abc']}

Comment: OK.  "Content of each cluster is the same" -- ?  Very ambiguous.  "Consecutive clusters" -- ?  Clusters have no ordering in general.

Comment: In your update it looks like you have a *single* string, which you're trying to partition into substrings in such a way as to optimise a cost function on just that partition.

Comment: in my exemple ('abc' string) I have 4 possible clusterings (the compositions)
in the first clustering ['a', 'b', 'c'] __content of each cluster__ is different ('a'!='b'!='c'). clusters 'a' and 'b' are __consecutive__ but 'a' and 'c' are not.

Comment: OK, now that you've edited to "a single string", a lot of things are clearer.  "Clustering" is a bit misleading here -- IIUC you intend it to be synonymous with "composition" (or "partition into substrings"), but because you use both "clustering" and "composition" I thought they were supposed to mean different things.  I would just call the whole thing a "composition" or "partition into substrings", and the individual parts "substrings".

Comment: Are you trying to minimise or maximise?  You write "best score" (suggesting maximisation), but then your diagram uses "cost" (suggesting minimisation).

Comment: It's not clear whether your cost function (a) works on any composition, but assigns the best score to those meeting the 4 given conditions (if so: how does "Cluster sizes must be in a range [a, b]" make sense?), or (b) only works only on compositions that obey all 4 given conditions.

Comment: Finally, how can a composition simultaneously obey "Content of each cluster is the same" and "Consecutive clusters don't have the same content"?  No function can assign a "best score" to such a composition, because the set of compositions satisfying both requirements is empty!  I give up.

Comment: FWIW I suspect there's a DP algorithm with worst-case time complexity proportional to the string length times r^b, where r is the number of distinct symbols in the alphabet, which will be efficient if r and b are small, but I'm not going to try and solve every question that you *might be* asking.

Comment: what I mean by score or cost, is a positive real value that is given for all clustering (a product of scores given for the four criteria in the question).

The best clustering receives the highest score value

Comment: Then everything is determined by the relative weights assigned to each of the 4 criteria.  E.g. if min(weight(criterion 1), weight(criterion 2)) >= max(weight(criterion 3), weight(criterion 4)) and there is some i between a and b such that the string length is a multiple of i, then the optimal solution is just to find the i that gives the best value of weight(crit 3)*weight(crit 4) after dividing the string into length-i blocks -- O(n log n) time, since n cannot have more than log n factors that you need to try as potential i values.

Comment: In fact there are very few combinations to try overall, since e.g. `NOT crit 1` implies `NOT crit 3`, and `crit 3` and `crit 4` are mutually exclusive.  That's assuming that each criterion, if satisfied, contributes some specific factor to the score and otherwise contributes some lower factor, i.e. that no criterion gives "in-between" values for compositions that are in some sense "near" to being satisfied.  (You probably *do* have criteria that contribute such "in-between" values, but you haven't said so.)

Comment: in reality, cost function is not fixed yet. I'll change it (maybe just the weights) until I have the lowest cost in the cluster I want.

Comment: Starting to look better!  I don't have time right now, but I think there should be a DP that calculates this in O(n^2*(b-a)^2) time.  Basically: Define f(i, j, k) to be the minimum cost of any partition of the first i characters into exactly j substrings, and in which the final substring (i.e. the one ending at position i) uses exactly k characters (a <= k <= b).  We want to calculate max(f(n, j, k)) over all 1 <= j <= n and a <= k <= b, by using the solutions to subproblems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dynamic programming approach should work here.

Imagine, first, that a `cost(clustering)` equals to the sum of `cost(cluster)` for all all clusters that constitute the clustering.

Then, a simple DP function is defined as follows:

`F[i] = minimal cost of clustering the substring s[0:i]`

and calculated in the following way:

```
for i = 0..length(s)-1:
    for j = a..b:
        last_cluster = s[i-j..i]
        F[i] = min(F[i], F[i - j] + cost(last_cluster))
```

Of course, first you have to initialize values of F to some infinite values or nulls to correctly apply min function.

To actually restore the answer, you can store additional values `P[i]`, which would contain the lengths of the last cluster with optimal clustering of string s[0..i].
When you update F[i], you also update `P[i]`.

Then, restoring answer is little trouble:

```
current_pos = length(s) - 1
while (current_pos >= 0):
    current_cluster_length = P[current_pos]
    current_cluster = s[(current_pos - current_cluster_length + 1)..current_pos]
    // grab current_cluster to the answer
    current_pos -= current_cluster_length
```

Note that in this approach you will get the clsuters in the inverse order, meaning from the last cluster all the way to the first one.

Let's now apply this idea to the initial problem.
What we would like is to make cost(clustering) more or less linear, so that we can compute it cluster by cluster instead of computing it for the whole clustering.

The first parameter of our DP function `F` will be, as before, `i`, the number of chars in the substring `s[0:i]` we have found optimal answer to.
The meaning of the `F` function is, as usual, the minimal cost we can achieve with the given parameters.

The parameter `e = mean(clusters_entropies)` of the cost function is already linear and can be computed cluster by cluster, so this is not a problem.

The parameter `l = variance(cluster_lengths)` is a little bit more complex. 
The variance of `n` values is defined as `Sum[(x[i] - mean)^2] / n`.
`mean` is expected value, namely `mean = Sum[x[i]] / n`.
Note also that `Sum[x[i]]` is the sum of lengths of all clusters and in our case it is always fixed and equals to `length(s)`.
Therefore, `mean = length(s) / n`.
Okay, we have more or less made our `l` part of cost function linear except the `n` parameter. We will add this parameter, namely the number of clusters in the desired clustering, as a parameter to our `F` function.
We will also have a parameter `cur` which will mean the number of clusters currently assembled in the given state.

The parameter `d` of the cost function also requires adding additional parameter to our DP function `F`, namely `j`, `sz`, the size of the last cluster in our partition.

Overall, we have come up with a DP function `F[i][n][cur][sz]` that gives us the minimal cost function of partitioning string `s[0:i]` into `n` clusters of which `cur` are currently constructed with the size of the last cluster equal to `sz`. Of course, our responsibility is to make sure that `a<=sz<=b`.
The answer in terms of the minimal cost function will be the minimum among all possible `n` and `a<=sz<=b` values of DP function `F[length(s)-1][n][n][sz]`.
Now notice that this time we do not even require the companion `P` function to store the length of the last cluster as we already included that information as the last `sz` parameter into our `F` function.
We will, however, store in `P[i][n][cur][sz]` the length of the next to last cluster in the optimal clustering with the specified parameters. We will use that value to restore our solution.
Thus, we will be able to restore an answer in the following way, assuming the minimum of `F` is achieved in the parameters `n=n0` and `sz=sz0`:

```
current_pos = length(s) - 1
current_n = n0
current_cluster_size = sz0
while (current_n > 0):
    current_cluster = s[(current_pos - current_cluster_size + 1)..current_pos]
    next_cluster_size = P[current_pos][n0][current_n][current_cluster_size]
    current_n--;
    current_pos -= current_cluster_size;
    current_cluster_size = next_cluster_size
```

Let's now get to the computation of `F`.
I will omit the corner cases and range checks, but it will be enough to just initialize `F` with some infinite values.

```
// initialize for the case of one cluster
// d = 0, l = 0, only have to calculate entropy
for i=0..length(s)-1:
    for n=1..length(s):
        F[i][n][1][i+1] = cluster_entropy(s[0..i]);
        P[i][n][1][i+1] = -1; // initialize with fake value as in this case there is no previous cluster

// general case computation
for i=0..length(s)-1:
    for n=1..length(s):
        for cur=2..n:
            for sz=a..b:
                for prev_sz=a..b:
                    cur_cluster = s[i-sz+1..i]
                    prev_cluster = s[i-sz-prev_sz+1..i-sz]
                    F[i][n][cur][sz] = min(F[i][n][cur][sz], F[i-sz][n][cur - 1][prev_sz] + gamma*calc_d(prev_cluster, cur_cluster) + beta*cluster_entropy(cur_cluster)/n + alpha*(sz - s/n)^2)
```

Comment: This isn't a code ready to be copy-pasted and submitted if, say, it is your homework assignment, but if you just read and comprehend the logic behind the `F` function computation, then it will become really crystal clear. Any questions are welcome.

Comment: I think `beta*cluster_entropy(cur_cluster)` should have a `/n` appended.  Also your claim "The parameter e = mean(clusters_entropies) of the cost function is already linear and can be computed cluster by cluster, so this is not a problem" isn't enough to let you compute the mean cluster by cluster, since this depends on the number of clusters, but you wind up (for other reasons?) recording that in `cur` anyway so it all works :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker, nice catch, thank you! Indeed, we should divide it by `n` so that it's handled just like variance.